# Custom type conversion operator doesn't work when invoked on a forwarding reference (works when object is passed by value)

Tags: c++, c++17, constexpr, rvalue-reference, pass-by-rvalue-reference

I can't fathom the essence of this error so pardon me if the title could be better. This code fails to compile:

```
template <auto v>
struct value_as_type {
    using type = decltype(v);    
    static constexpr type value {v};
    constexpr operator type() const {
        return v;
    }
};

template <int First, int Last, typename Functor>
constexpr void static_for([[maybe_unused]] Functor&& f)
{
    if constexpr (First < Last)
    {
        f(value_as_type<First>{});
        static_for<First + 1, Last, Functor>(std::forward<Functor>(f));
    }
}

template <class... FieldsSequence>
struct DbRecord
{
private:
    static constexpr bool checkAssertions()
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(FieldsSequence) > 0);
        static_for<1, sizeof...(FieldsSequence)>([](auto&& index) {
            constexpr int i = index;
            static_assert(i > 0 && i < sizeof...(FieldsSequence));
        });

        return true;
    }

private:
    static_assert(checkAssertions());
};
```

The faulting line is `constexpr int i = index;`, and the error is "expression did not evaluate to a constant".

Why is this? I expect the conversion operator of the `value_as_type<int>` object to be invoked. And most confusingly, it does work just fine if the lambda takes `auto index` rather than `auto&& index`.

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/TffIIn

Comment: `index` is not a compile-time constant inside the lambda

Comment: And your whole `value_as_type` makes no sense to me, since it takes a number as a template argument and converts it to the same type it already is, so what is the difference between calling `f(value_as_type<First>{});` and simply `f(First);`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: that doesn't explain why it works without `&&`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: If all else fails, I can use `decltype(index)::value`, that's the sense. But I don't see why a conversion operator shouldn't work. Maybe in this particular case your suggested simplification would work, I shall try it (it certainly didn't work pre-C++17).

Comment: @RemyLebeau It doesn't have to be; `index.constexpr operator type()` doesn't depend on the compile-time constantness of the `index` variable.

Comment: I think I ran into this once.  Something about taking the address of the non-local reference causing it to fail to be constexpr, and the address being taken by the method call...  It felt standard-defect-y.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: but my code isn't taking address of anything, or is it? Do you mean implicitly, by virtue of rvalue reference?

Comment: @violet the `this` pointer.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe a reference, whether lvalue or rvalue, is a memory address and may not work at compile-time. Also, the lambda itself that `checkAssertions()` is passing to `static_for()` is not a `constexpr`, so it can't be used with a `constexpr` function at compile-time (prior to C++17, anyway). Have a look at [constexpr specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) and [Core constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Core_constant_expressions) for all the things a constexpr can and cannot do.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: well, I'm not taking about earlier standards, I'm compiling with C++17 and has tagged the question accordingly. I believe lambdas are now constexpr by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shorter reproduction, consider the difference between a program compiled with `ACCEPT` and a program without:

```
struct One { constexpr operator int() const { return 1; } };

template <typename T>
constexpr int foo(T&& t) {
#ifdef ACCEPT
    return t;
#else
    constexpr int i = t;
    return i;
#endif
}

constexpr int i = foo(One{});
```

As my choice of macro might suggest, the `ACCEPT` case is ok and the other case is ill-formed. Why? The rule in question is [[expr.const]/4.12](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#4.12):

> An expression `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following: [...] an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either [...]

What is *preceding initialization*? Before I answer that, lemme provide a different program and walk through what the semantics of it have to be:

#### A contradiction

```
struct Int { constexpr operator int() const { return i; } int i; };
template <int> struct X { };

template <typename T>
constexpr auto foo(T&& t) {
    constexpr int i = t;
    return X<i>{};
}

constexpr auto i = foo(Int{1});
constexpr auto j = foo(Int{2});
```

There is only one function `foo<Int>`, so it has to have one specific return type. If this program were allowed, then `foo(Int{1})` would return an `X<1>` and `foo(Int{2})` would return an `X<2>` -- that is, `foo<Int>` can return different types? This cannot happen, so this has to be ill-formed.

#### The smallest possible box

When we're in a situation that requires a constant expression, think of it as opening a new box. Everything within that box must satisfy the rules of the constant evaluation as if we'd just started from that point. If we require a new constant expression nested within that box, we open a new box. Boxes all the way down.

In both the original reproduction (with `One`) and the new reproduction (with `Int`), we have this declaration:

```
constexpr int i = t;
```

This opens a new box. The initializer, `t`, has to satisfy the restrictions of constant expressions. `t` is a reference type, but has no preceding initialization *within this box*, hence this is ill-formed.

Now in the accepted case:

```
struct One { constexpr operator int() const { return 1; } };

template <typename T>
constexpr int foo(T&& t) {
    return t;
}

constexpr int i = foo(One{});
```

We only have the one box: the initialization of the global `i`. Within that box, we do still evaluate an *id-expression* of reference type, within that `return t;`, but in this case we *do* have a preceding initialization within our box: we have visibility where we bind `t` to `One{}`. So this works. There is no contradiction that can be constructed from these rules. Indeed, this would be fine too:

```
constexpr int j = foo(Int{1});
constexpr int k = foo(Int{2});
static_assert(i+k == 3);
```

Because we still just have the one entrance each time into constant evaluation, and within that evaluation, the reference `t` has preceding initialization, and the members of `Int` are usable in constant expressions also.

#### Back to the OP

Removing the reference works because we no longer violate the reference restriction, and there isn't any other restriction that we could violate. We're not reading any variable state or anything, the conversion function just returns a constant.

A similar example where we tried to pass `Int{1}` to `foo` by value would still fail - not for the reference rule this time, but instead for the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion rule. Basically, we're reading something that we can't be allowed to read -- because we'd end up with the same kind of contradiction of being able to construct a function with multiple return types.

Comment: Very interesting, many thanks for the detailed and clever explanation. I understand why multiple return types is not OK, but I still have difficulty understanding why reference in a completely compile-time context is not OK, and especially why it may or may not be OK depending on the outside code. So basically, are you saying the compiler is unable to analyze and chain compile-time calls through nested "boxes"?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe This is, in my opinion, the most complicated part of the language to understand.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe I don't think it's right to say the compiler is _unable_ to. I think rather, it's not possible to support.

Comment: Will the rules be any different in C++20 with `constinit` and `consteval` keywords instead of somewhat ambiguous `conxtexpr`?

Comment: Calling a non-static member function on something that's not an object of the right type within its lifetime is undefined behavior. Constant evaluation must catch all undefined behavior. It follows that you cannot perform such a call unless the referent is known (i.e., "has a preceding initialization").

Comment: @T.C., but it is known to the compiler since everything is available at compile time!

Comment: The well-formed-ness of a function cannot depend on how it is called.